# Android sql element to listview

Tags: android, sql, listview

I have a table in sql database with values: id, name, age, weight and can get them into a List values.
the list should look like this:
name
age:  weight:

how can i achieve that? I've tried to pass the list to ArrayAdapter, but i dont know how exactly. when i use this:
    `ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Person>(this, R.layout.list_example_entry, values);`
i get `android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you have to build a custom adapter and inflate your custom row layout. Using ArrayAdapter won't work

So, your custom adapter class could be somthing like:

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private final Activity activity;
        private final List list;

        public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Person> list) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.list = list;
        }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View rowView = convertView;
            ViewHolder view;

            if(rowView == null)
            {
                // Get a new instance of the row layout view
                LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);

                // Hold the view objects in an object, that way the don't need to be "re-  finded"
                view = new ViewHolder();
                view.person_name= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                view.person_address= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.address);

                rowView.setTag(view);
            } else {
                view = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            }

            /** Set data to your Views. */
            Person item = list.get(position);
            view.person_name.setText(item.getTickerSymbol());
            view.person_address.setText(item.getQuote().toString());

            return rowView;
        }

        protected static class ViewHolder{
            protected TextView person_name;
            protected TextView person_address;
        }
    }
```

And your Person.java class could as simple as I describe below:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public Person(String name, String address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address= address;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}
```

Now, in you main activity just bind you list with some data, like;

```
/** Declare and initialize list of Person. */
ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();

/** Add some restaurants to the list. */
list.add(new Person("name1", "address1"));
list.add(new Person("name2", "address2"));
list.add(new Person("name3", "address3"));
list.add(new Person("name4", "address4"));
list.add(new Person("name5", "address5"));
list.add(new Person("name6", "address6"));
At this point you're able to set the custom adapter to your list

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);

CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(YourMainActivityName.this, list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: maybe a silly error, but I cant even create `public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Person> list) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.list = list;
    }` it says there is no default constructor available in ArrayAdaptor

Comment: Error:(23, 73) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter

Comment: try changing the ArrayAdapter with BaseAdapter

Comment: but then I either have to declare it abstract or implement abstract method 'getItemId(int)' in 'Adapter' which i dont know anything about

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a `CursorAdapter` for this. There's a nice guide here: [Loading Data in the Background](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html)